# Parallel programming with nested loops using OpenMP in C

Tags: c, multithreading, parallel-processing, openmp

So, I am dealing with getting multiple threads to work with both the inner and outer loop of a double nested loop in C. I am having it run on a remote server at LONI which is using 20 processors. I am executing 81 threads for this. I tried using collapse directive and that failed because of intervening code in between the two loops. I need to have that code in there as the inner loop works on lines from a file read sequentially just before it. Thanks in advance guys. Let me know how I can correctly put directives in this code to run efficiently.

```
#include <omp.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>

#define MAX 20000                    //number of vertices we are working with
#define EACHLINE 99000               //number of characters each line of file could be

//function for getting the intersecton of two arrays representing our lists
void getIntersections(int one[], int two[], int l1, int l2){   //arrays and their sizes
    printf("%d & %d: [ ", one[0], two[0]);
    for(int o=1; o<l1; o++){
       for(int t=1; t<l2; t++){
           if(one[o]==two[t]){
              printf("%d ", one[o]);
              break;
           }
       }
    }
    printf("]\n");
 }

 //getting common ones out of the adjacency lists with vertices v1 & v2
 void getLists(int v1, int v2){
     FILE* np;
     np = fopen("r2.txt", "r");

     int arr1[MAX], arr2[MAX], length1 = 0, length2 = 0, c, bytesread;
     char input[EACHLINE];
     char* str;

     fgets(input, sizeof(input), np);
     str = input;
     while (sscanf(str, "%d%n", &c, &bytesread) > 0) {    //changing string of spaced numbers to int array
          arr1[length1++] = c;
          str += bytesread;
     }

     while(arr1[0] != v1 && arr1[0] != v2){                           
     //increment until we hit line v1 or v2
         length1 = 0;
         fgets(input, sizeof(input), np);
         str = input;
         while (sscanf(str, "%d%n", &c, &bytesread) > 0) {
             arr1[length1++] = c;
             str += bytesread;
         }  
    }

    arr2[0] = -1;

    while(arr2[0] != v1 && arr2[0] != v2){                           
    //increment until we hit line v1 or v2
        length2 = 0;
        fgets(input, sizeof(input), np);
        str = input;
        while (sscanf(str, "%d%n", &c, &bytesread) > 0) {
            arr2[length2++] = c;
            str += bytesread;
        }   
    }

    fclose(np);
    getIntersections(arr1, arr2, length1, length2);
}

int main(int argc, char** argv){
    FILE* fp;
    if((fp = fopen("r2.txt", "r")) == NULL){        //opens file
        perror("Error opening file!");
        return 1;
    }

    //getting number of lines in file
    FILE *tp = fopen("r2.txt","r");
    int ch=0;
    int lines=0;
    while ((ch = fgetc(tp)) != EOF){
        if (ch == '\n')
            lines++;
    }
    fclose(tp);

    char input[EACHLINE];

    clock_t start, end;     //clocks
    double cpu_time_used;   //time recorder
    start = clock();
    int r, j;
    for(r = 0; r < lines; r++){       //dividing task among processes
        int arr[MAX], length = 0, c, bytesread;         
        fgets(input, sizeof(input), fp);
        char* str = input;                              //list buffer
        while (sscanf(str, "%d%n", &c, &bytesread) > 0) {  //changing string of spaced numbers to int array
             arr[length++] = c;
             str += bytesread;
        } 

        for(j=1; j<length; j++){    
        //if it has been done before    
            if(arr[0]<arr[j]){
                getLists(arr[0], arr[j]);
            }
         }       
     }

     end = clock();  //timer stop
     cpu_time_used = ((double) (end - start)) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;   
     //time taken
     printf("Time: %f\n", cpu_time_used);

     fclose(fp);
     return 0;
}
```

Comment: can you please tell us what your program should do. And what is `getLists()`?

Comment: The code is trying to find the common numbers between lists represented by sequences of numbers in a line in the file fp. For instance, if I have 1 2 3 4 5 & 2 4 7 8, in lines 1 & 2, if 1 & 2 are the arguments for getLists, it would print out [2, 4].

Comment: Don't write this in the comments add this to your question, also we need the implementation of `getLists`. Also there are missing definitions for `MAX`, `fp`,`input`. Basically you have to include everything in the question so we can compile the code by copy and paste. But there should be not more code than necessary to see the problem. please read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Note that `fgets` is not thread-safe on the same fp, so you cannot parallelize the outer loop without significant refactoring. This is not just about "putting directives in the code". To run this efficiently we need a [mcve], which includes the input or a  way to generate it as well as a description of the system this code is supposed to run on (a dual core laptop with a local disk or a 100+ core shared memory machine with a parallel file system).

Comment: Sorry for the ambiguous question guys. I have edited it and included my complete code as well. Thanks for the input guys. I had thought of reading the entire file first so that I could use collapse but it is so large that having a 20000 x 20000 array would go beyond available memory, and this is the smallest data set that I have had to handle.